# Caliburn.CoRoutine in VB

Tags: wpf, vb.net, desktop, caliburn.micro

I am trying to convert the CoRoutine Caliburn Sample from C# to VB the conversion was going well until I got to this statement in the bootstrapper:

```
Coroutine.Completed += (s, e) => {
    if (e.Error != null)
        MessageBox.Show(e.Error.Message);
};
```

This is in the configure section of the bootstrapper and I presume that it's purpose is to intercept any errors after the CoRoutine completion and post to a message box.

In VB this converts to:

```
Coroutine.Completed += Function(s, e)
                           If e.[Error] IsNot Nothing Then
                               MessageBox.Show(e.[Error].Message)
                           End If
                       End Function
```

This gets a squiggle in the editor and in VS 2015 the error message suggests that you should use a raise event, - - - however that doesn't seem to make sense where here in the bootstrapper, it appears to me that the purpose of the Lambda is to *handle* the event.

I would love to hear from anyone who also works with Caliburn in VB. Initial conversions of each of the Caliburn Samples is a real challenge, but is even more difficult for me because I and working in a WPF desktop app rather than Silverlight and while the two are similar, Silverlight examples presents a lot of gotchas.  I now have a library of close to 20 CM Desktop Samples all working in VB, which I would be happy to share, but CoRoutines have been an elusive devil to get working in VB

Answer (score 1):

use `AddHandler`

```
AddHandler Coroutine.Completed, 
    Sub(s, e)
        If e.[Error] IsNot Nothing Then
            MessageBox.Show(e.[Error].Message)
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: I think it should be 'Sub ... End Sub'. (Otherwise fine).

Comment: @user3418258, Glad to help. If this resolves your issue don't forget to mark as answer. Happy coding!!!